# Mysql query using values in JSONArray

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm posting a JSONArray.toString() to a php file.  The JSONArray contains a set of id values.  I want to make a mysql query that only returns rows that have an id contained in the jsonarray.  My method below isn't working.  Is there another way?

```
$jsonarray= $_POST["ids"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN $jsonarray")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: That's because the `JSONArray.toString()` probably ends up with `[1, 2, 3, 4]` thus the query is not valid. You should decode the json using `json_decode` and then implode the result with comma...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd help if we had an example of the JSON array, however, you should decode the JSON array into a comma separated list to use with IN.

```
$jsonarray = $_POST["ids"];
$ids = implode(",", json_decode($jsonarray,true));

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($ids)")or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, you should be using mysqli or PDO_MySQL for new development:

> It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. It
>   is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development.
>   A detailed feature comparison matrix is provided below. The overall
>   performance of all three extensions is considered to be about the
>   same. Although the performance of the extension contributes only a
>   fraction of the total run time of a PHP web request. Often, the impact
>   is as low as 0.1%.

**Related Reading:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php

Comment: I would add to your answer that it is better to use mysqli or PDO as mysql_ API is discouraged and will be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

echo out the contents of $jsonarray and you will see the error when you check the syntax of the MySQL query

Comment: actually I think the user would learn a lot more by doing this but I accept it was a bit vague. he/she will paste in code from @christains answer and not understand what they were doing wrong.

Comment: It's all OK, I agree with You, but this is not an answer to the question.