# Select data based on two constraints for each row, using JSON data as input

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that keeps a column for versioning of the entries. Client applications should be able to query the server with their current versions and IDs, and the server respond with the rows that have a higher version for each of the entries. I am not an expert on `MySQL`, so I cannot see how to achieve this. I have tried various things, but I am currently far from producing anything that works efficiently.

## Example:

**Server data:**

```
mysql> SELECT id, version FROM my_data;
+-----+---------+
| id  | version |
+-----+---------+
|   1 |       0 |
|   2 |       1 |
|   3 |       2 | <-- The JSON data below has lower version, so this row should be selected.
|   4 |       0 |
|   5 |       1 |
|   6 |       0 |
|   7 |       1 | <-- The JSON data below has lower version, so this row should be selected.
|   8 |       1 |
|   9 |       4 | <-- The JSON data below has lower version, so this row should be selected.
|  10 |       1 |
+-----+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Data sent from the client:**

The client then queries the server with the following data in JSON (or whatever, but I have JSON in my case). The server side is `php` and I need to parse this JSON data and include it in the query somehow. **This is the data the client currently contains.**

```
{
    "my_data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "version": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "version": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "version": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "version": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "version": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

In this example I want the `MySQL` query to return 3 rows; namely the 3 rows with `id` 3, 7 and 9 because the client version is lower than the server version, thus it needs to fetch some data for updating. How can I achieve this in a single, simple query? I do not want to run one query for each row, even if this *is* possible.

**Desired result from the sample data:**

The resulting data should be the rows in which the version in the database on the server side is greater than the data with the *corresponding* `id` in the JSON data set.

```
mysql> <INSERT PROPER QUERY HERE>;
+-----+---------+
| id  | version |
+-----+---------+
|   3 |       2 |
|   7 |       1 |
|   9 |       4 |
+-----+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That does not take the version into consideration. I do not know which of the rows on the server that have versions greater than the data in the incoming JSON set. If I did it would be this simple.

Comment: How big is this table, how many rows

Comment: we need you php code to...

Comment: based on what Desired result is coming .

Comment: It is currently ~200 rows. It will grow in the future, but it is not likely to be more than around 1000 - 1200 rows at any point.

Comment: The question seems unclear to me, make it clear: I have x,y,z and I need: ....

Comment: you'll have to make a loop of a one object query as far as I see

Comment: The desired results should contain the rows in which the database version is greater than the corresponding version in the JSON data set from the client.

Comment: Please add few more details to your question. I didn't find any condition which can get you desired result.

Comment: Will the json be greater thn 20 elements?

Comment: Yes, the JSON will have approximately the same number of elements as on the server side at any given point. Never more than the server side, because the client is updated based on what is on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main result for the below results and discussions: Using the multiple `OR` query (as suggested by @KA_lin) is faster for small data sets (`n < 1000` or so). This approach scales badly for larger data sets however, so I will probably stick with using a query with the `TEMPORARY TABLE` approach below in case my data set should grow large in the future. The payload for this is not that high.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_data_virtual(id INTEGER NOT NULL, version TINYINT(3) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_data_virtual VALUES
    (1,0), (2,1), (3,0), (4,0), (5,1),
    (6,0), (7,0), (8,1), (9,2), (10,1);

SELECT md.id, md.version
    FROM my_data AS md
    INNER JOIN my_data_virtual AS mdv
        ON md.id = mvd.id AND md.id > mvd.id;
```

I ran a series of tests using the `MySQLdb` and `timeit` modules in Python. I created 5 tables: `test_100`, `test_500`, `test_1000`, `test_5000` and `test_10000`. All the databases were given a single table, `data`, which contained the following columns.

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version     | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| description | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The tables in the databases were then filled with random versions from 0 to 5 and a semi-random amount of lorem ipsum text. The `test_100.data` table got 100 rows, the `test_500.data` table got 500 rows and so forth. I then ran test for both the query using nested `OR` statements and using a temporary table with all `id`s and random version between 0 and 5.

## Results

**Results for nested `OR` query. Number of repeats for each `n` was 1000.**

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|          | n = 100     | n = 500     | n = 1000    | n = 5000    | n = 10000   |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| max      | 0.00719     | 0.02213     | 0.04325     | 1.75707     | 8.91687     |
| min      | 0.00077     | 0.00781     | 0.02696     | 0.63565     | 5.29613     |
| median   | 0.00100     | 0.00917     | 0.02996     | 0.82732     | 5.92217     |
| average  | 0.00111     | 0.01001     | 0.03057     | 0.82540     | 5.89577     |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Results for temporary table query. Number of repeats for each `n` was 1000.**

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|          | n = 100     | n = 500     | n = 1000    | n = 5000    | n = 10000   |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| max      | 0.06352     | 0.07192     | 0.08798     | 0.28648     | 0.26939     |
| min      | 0.02119     | 0.02027     | 0.03126     | 0.07677     | 0.12269     |
| median   | 0.03075     | 0.03210     | 0.043833    | 0.10068     | 0.15839     |
| average  | 0.03121     | 0.03258     | 0.044968    | 0.10342     | 0.16153     |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

It seems that using nested `OR` queries is faster up to about `n = 1000`. From there on, the the nested `OR` scales badly and the temporary table approach wins solidly. In my case I am likely to have a maximum of around 1000 rows, so it seems that I can choose between these two approaches relatively freely.

**I will probably go for the temporary table approach in case my data set should become larger than expected. The payload is small in any case.**

## Notes

- Since the `timeit` module in Python is a bit ticklish, the database is opened and closed for each run/repeat. This might produce some overhead to the timings.
- The queries for the temporary table approach were done in 3 steps: 1 for creating the temporary, 1 for inserting the data and 1 for joining the tables.
- The creation of the queries are *not* part of the timing; they are created outside of the Python `timeit` call.
- Since both the versions in the inserted data and the random "client" data are randomly chosen between 0 and 5, it is likely that between 33 % and 50 % of the rows are selected. I have *not* verified this. This is not really the case I have, as the client data will at any point have *almost* the same data as the server.
- I tried adding `WHERE id IN (1,2,3...,10)` on both the temporary table approach and the nested `OR` approach, but it neither sped things up nor slowed them down in any of the tests, except for the larger data sets and the multiple `OR` approach. Here, the times were *slightly* lower than without this `WHERE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: Not used PDO, just query string generation, can be switched easily

To check each version you can do an `OR` statement for each id but check first that the **json is not empty first**

```
$jsonData = json_decode($inputJson, true);
$jsonData = $jsonData['my_data'];
$string = 'select * from my_data where';
foreach($jsonData as $data) {
    $conditions[] = '(id='.$data['id'].' and version>'.$data['version'].')';
}
$string .=implode('or', $conditions);
```

result:

```
select * from my_data where (id=1 and version>0) or (id=2 and version>0)
```

Comment: The intention was to create the query string

Comment: yes, but don't forget to add a warning on SQL injection when you send answer with crafted unsafe sql query :P

Comment: This approach works fine and is faster than using a `TEMPORARY TABLE` approach for small data sets, see test results in my answer. For larger data sets this is not feasible, however, thus it might be a better to use a temporary table in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,version FROM my_data WHERE `id` = $APP_ID AND `version` > $APP_VERSION;
```

Replace `$APP_ID` with an actual item ID and respectively `$APP_ID` with ID coming from incoming JSON.

Answer (score 0):

something like that no ?

```
try{
  $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
}
catch (Exception $e){
  die('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$output = array();

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT `id`, `version` FROM my_data WHERE `id` = :id AND `version` > :version');

foreach($yourJson as $object){
  $req->execute(array('id' => $object['id'], 'prixmax' => $object['version']));
  $data = $req->fetch();
  if(!empty($data))
    $output[] = $data;
}

echo $data
```

Answer (score 0):

That you have to do with json_array_elements:

```
SELECT id, version 
FROM my_data AS md, json_array_elements(md.json_col->'version') AS jsonVersion
WHERE  version > jsonVersion->>'version';
```

json_col being the name of the JSON column.

I am providing few links might be it will helpful to you.

More details in this related answer:

[How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)

More about the implicit CROSS JOIN LATERAL in the last paragraph of this related answer:
[PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Advanced example

[Query combinations with nested array of records in JSON datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877241/query-combinations-with-nested-array-of-records-in-json-datatype/26880705#26880705)

Hope you will get solution.

Comment: It's a MySQL subject >_>

Comment: i was having same issue i got solution from this. 
check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727550/mysql-query-using-values-in-jsonarray